# S3 image links won't show on Chromecast (Rails web app inside Swift iOS wrapper)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, amazon-s3, chromecast

first post but longtime user (my hair/sanity has been saved by SO on many occasions).

I am struggling to get images hosted on S3 to show on a Chromecast.

I have a Rails web app that sends an image link via websockets (Action Cable) to an iOS wrapper app (in Swift), which in turn sends the link to a connected default Chromecast receiver to display the image on screen. This convoluted route is necessary due to my use case and the Cast SDK.

This works perfectly and the Chromecast correctly displays images sent from the web app itself (i.e. relative path links to images hosted on Heroku), as well as direct links (such as this public [image of a plane](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png). However, it won’t show images that I have hosted on AWS S3.

The [Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) doesn't show any issues with the image formats (jpg, png) or links that would be relevant, so the issue is presumably with the S3 link, not the cast itself.

I use Active Storage to connect my rails app to S3 and `url_for(artwork.image)` to show the correct image inside the app.

I also generate a full link for my Javascript frontend as per the wonderful [Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files)

```
*my_channel.rb*

indirect_link = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(artwork.image, only_path: true)
```

This indirect link routes via the web app and then on to S3, for security reasons. This works for my javascript page updates, but the Cast wasn’t able to display this link.

I figured it didn’t like the redirection, so I generated the full signed direct link instead after some trial and error using the [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html)

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'eu-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket(‘bucket name’).object(‘key’)
direct_url = obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 3600)
```

This worked in the app and also from any browser, so seemed to be as public as possible. But again the Cast couldn’t display it.

I then tried editing the CORS for the S3 bucket, following the [AWS S3 CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html) guide. I tried both of these options, but neither worked.

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
```

I also tried making my S3 bucket completely [public](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html), and also making an individual image public, but neither worked (and in any case, the signed direct link generated 
above is already public and can be accessed from any browser).

I have access to the iOS code (in Swift), which details the Cast setup etc, but I don’t know Swift and can’t access any error messages unfortunately. As such, I can’t use the [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629844/chromecast-debugger-works-but-does-not-show-anything/28634037). As it is working successfully for other public links, I think the issue is most likely with the S3 link (although this assumption may be wrong) or the types of links that the Cast allows.

I've spent a number of days on this and I'm out of ideas at this point so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own question - it turns out that the iOS wrapper had the error (specifically, it required an unrelated value to be submitted at the same time, which has now been compensated for).

On the plus side, both the indirect and direct S3 link methods in my question work via Casting, so hopefully they will be useful to someone in a similar position looking to create those links in future.

Comment: Hi! Can I ask what you mean by unrelated value?